# Parsing Javascript Data Object in Java

Tags: javascript, selenium

Hello i need help in parsing an object that is being return to java. I am running some automated tests using selenium. In my test i am using the framework to call javascript functions and what i am doing is assigning what is passed back from the javascript function to a java object. The event object passed from javascript looks like this

```
{
  data={
    isFailover=false,
    baseClip={
        expression=full,
        isAd=true,
        connectionBitrate=0,
        baseURL=null,
        contentCustomData={
            fw: titleId=null,
            fw: advertiserId=null,
            fw: category=null
          },
          overlays=[],
          ratings=[]
        }
    }
}
```

I have an object called "responseToMediaIsAd" defined as

private static Object responseToMediaIsAd;

The data response is being outputted (above) comes when i do this

System.out.println(responseToMediaIsAd);

So its great that i get data back:-) The only problem now is HOW do i parse thru this data. do i have to convert it to json then parse that data?... Can someone tell me how to read the value of (say isFailover, and isAd), ie need to know how to step through and get values

I need to know how to use Java to get to this data that Javascript is returning. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the Jackson JSON parser library, or if you know regex, you can painfully roll a custom one with some crafted queries.